# Can an Enterprise Application on Azure AD be assigned differently scoped permissions?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization

Our use case is this: our application needs to access the Azure AD of customer organizations to:

- Authenticate users
- Sync users' profile data to our app when it changes on AD
- Read and subscribe to booking changes in meeting rooms

Our app therefore needs the `User.Read.All` permission to read profiles of users, but also `Calendar.Read.All` but the latter must be scoped to a specific group (so as the protect the privacy of actual users). According to [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/scoping-microsoft-graph-application-permissions-to-specific/ba-p/671881), a tenant administrator can restrict access of an application to a specific group, but I don't see any way to do this for a single permission, so it would restrict all permissions of an enterprise app to this group. Am I missing something or is this simply impossible and I would need to use multiple service accounts for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we can not restric the specific application permission to access a specific group. But we can scope application permissions to **specific Exchange Online mailboxes**.

Administrators can use ApplicationAccessPolicy cmdlets to control mailbox access of an app that has been granted any of the following application permissions:

- Mail.Read
- Mail.ReadBasic
- Mail.ReadBasic.All
- Mail.ReadWrite
- Mail.Send
- MailboxSettings.Read
- MailboxSettings.ReadWrite
- Calendars.Read
- Calendars.ReadWrite
- Contacts.Read
- Contacts.ReadWrite

So if you have both `User.Read.All` and `Calendar.Read`, the ApplicationAccessPolicy will only work for `Calendar.Read` permission. The ApplicationAccessPolicy are specific to Exchange Online resources and **do not apply to other Microsoft Graph** workloads.

Comment: We're talking about a background service here so users aren't involved in the process.

Comment: Ok so you're saying this is generally impossible?

Comment: It is possible to restrict the application to a particular security group, but, as I understand, all of its permissions will then be restricted to that group.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm Updated the answer, hope this can answer your question clearly. Only the permissions listed in the answer will be restriced to that group.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that. Thanks!